# C# Working with delegates (the name does not exist in current context)

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I have the following code:

```
using System;
namespace Laboratory_work
{

    public delegate void Delegate ();
    public interface Method1
    {
        string InformationOutput (Person obj);
        int WorkOffer();
    }
    public interface Method2
    {
        int Invitation();
    }

    public abstract class Person: Method1
    {
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public string Surname{get; set;}
        public int Age{get; set;}
        public virtual string InformationOutput(Person obj)
        {
            string info="Some personal information \n_________________________\n\n"+
                "Full name — "+Name+" "+Surname+
                "\nAge — "+Age+" years\n";
            return info;
        }
        public int WorkOffer()
        {
            if (Age>=18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou may be offered a job.");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnfortunately, there is no job for you.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public class WhiteCollarWorker: Person, Method1
    {
        public string Occupation{get; set;}
        public bool ComputerAvailable{get; set;}
        public override string InformationOutput(Person obj)
        {
            return base.InformationOutput(obj)+"Occupation — "+Occupation+"\n"+
                "Computer — "+ComputerAvailable+"\n";
        }
        public int WorkOffer()
        {
            if (Age>=21 && Occupation!="\0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou may be offered a job.");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnfortunately, there is no job for you.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Laborer: Person, Method1
    {
        public string Occupation{get; set;}
        public bool InstrumentsAvailable{get; set;}
        public override string InformationOutput(Person obj)
        {
            return base.InformationOutput(obj)+"Occupation — "+Occupation+"\n"+
                "Instruments — "+InstrumentsAvailable+"\n";
        }
        public int WorkOffer()
        {
            if (Age>=18 && Occupation!="\0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou may be offered a job.");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnfortunately, there is no job for you.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Engineer: WhiteCollarWorker, Method1, Method2
    {
        public int YearExperience{get; set;}
        public bool BachelorDegree{get; set;}
        public bool MasterDegree{get; set;}
        public override string InformationOutput(Person obj)
        {
            return base.InformationOutput(obj)+"Experience — "+YearExperience+" year(s)\n"+
                "Bachelor Degree — "+BachelorDegree+"\n"+
                "Master Degree — "+MasterDegree+"\n";
        }
        public int WorkOffer()
        {
            if (Age>=25 && YearExperience>=1 && BachelorDegree==true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou may be offered a job.");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnfortunately, there is no job for you.");
                return 0;
            }

        }
        public int Invitation()
        {
            if(WorkOffer()==1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dear "+Name+" "+Surname+", soon you will receive\n"+
                                  "an email with date and time of your interview\n"+
                                  "at out company.Thank you for your CV.");
                return 1;                  
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dear "+Name+" "+Surname+", unfortunately, you are\n"+
                                  "not suitable for this position. Than you for your CV.\n");
                return 0;  
            }
        }
    }

    public class Builder: Laborer, Method1, Method2
    {
        public int YearExperience {get; set;}
        public bool Education {get; set;}
        public override string InformationOutput(Person obj)
        {
            return base.InformationOutput(obj)+"Experience — "+YearExperience+" year(s)\n"+
                "Education — "+Education+"\n";
        }
        public int WorkOffer()
        {
            if (Age>=18 && (YearExperience>=1 || Education==true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou may be offered a job.");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnfortunately, there is no job for you.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        public int Invitation()
        {
            if(WorkOffer()==1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dear "+Name+" "+Surname+", soon you will receive\n"+
                                  "an email with date and time of your interview\n"+
                                  "at out company.Thank you for your CV.");
                return 1;                  
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dear "+Name+" "+Surname+", unfortunately, you are\n"+
                                  "not suitable for this position. Than you for your CV.\n");
                return 0;  
            }
        }


    }
    class Program
    {   
    public static void Main()
    {
        Delegate Del_1=new Delegate(WorkOffer);
        Delegate Del_2=new Delegate(Invitation);
        Delegate TwoDels=new Delegate(Del_1+Del_2);

        const int N=10;
        int Count=0;

        var persons1=new Engineer[N];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            persons1[i] = new Engineer();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nENGINEERS\n________\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Input information of a person");
            Console.Write("Name: ");
            persons1[i].Name=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Surname: ");
            persons1[i].Surname=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Age: ");
            persons1[i].Age=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Occupation: ");
            persons1[i].Occupation=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Computer (true or false): ");
            persons1[i].ComputerAvailable=bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Experience (in years): ");
            persons1[i].YearExperience=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Bachelor Degree (true or false): ");
            persons1[i].BachelorDegree=bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Master Degree (true or false): ");
            persons1[i].MasterDegree=bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (Print 'OK' or 'NO'.)");
            string answer;
            answer=Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer=="OK"||answer=="ok") continue;
            else break;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n#"+(i+1));
            Console.WriteLine(persons1[i].InformationOutput(persons1[i]));
        }
        Count=0;
        var persons2=new Builder[N];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            persons2[i] = new Builder();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nBUILDERS\n________\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Input information of a person");
            Console.Write("Name: ");
            persons2[i].Name=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Surname: ");
            persons2[i].Surname=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Age: ");
            persons2[i].Age=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Occupation: ");
            persons2[i].Occupation=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Instruments (true or false): ");
            persons2[i].InstrumentsAvailable=bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Experience (in years): ");
            persons2[i].YearExperience=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Education (true or false): ");
            persons2[i].Education=bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (Print 'OK' or 'NO'.)");
            string answer;
            answer=Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer=="OK"||answer=="ok") continue;
            else break;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n#"+(i+1));
            Console.WriteLine(persons2[i].InformationOutput(persons2[i]));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue . . .");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    }
}
```

It loos really big, so I want to pay your atention to the lines 176-178:

```
Delegate Del_1=new Delegate(WorkOffer);
Delegate Del_2=new Delegate(Invitation);
Delegate TwoDels=new Delegate(Del_1+Del_2);
```

Here I'm trying to create examples of Delegate, bur something goes wrong. Compiler shows errors "The name 'WorkOffer' does not exist in current context" and "The name 'Invitation' does not exist in current context".
I think that's all because I try to use them out of the class where these methods were declare, but what should I do then to use delegates connected to these methods in my program? I need some advice.

Comment: If it's public,i don't think there should be a problem to use them accross classes,just call them as follows : `MyClassName.DelegateName`

Comment: You are referencing a method in a class, without an instance, so C# is looking for the method in the current `Program` class, which it cannot find. You need to associate those delegates with a specific class instance.

Comment: `WorkOffer` and `Invitation` are object members. You need an object that implements the appropriate interface, otherwise there's no way to know which object you want the delegate to call the method for.

Comment: Yes the problem is that these are instance methods and you do not have an instance of Builder/Person/etc. What are you intending to do with Del1 and Del2? Also it is best to avoid name collisions with core system classes like System.Delegate. Besides there is already a delegate type defined with this signature anyway, it is System.Action. Use that instead of defining your own.